# implementing dijkstra algorithm in elogv time

Tags: c++, algorithm

```
1) Create a Min Heap of size V where V is the number of vertices in the given graph. 
   Every node of min heap contains vertex number and distance value of the vertex.
2) Initialize Min Heap with source vertex as root (the distance value assigned to source
   vertex is 0). The distance value assigned to all other vertices is INF (infinite).
3) While Min Heap is not empty, do following
    a) Extract the vertex with minimum distance value node from Min Heap. Let the 
    extracted vertex be u.
    b) For every adjacent vertex v of u, check if v is in Min Heap. If v is in Min Heap
       and distance value is more than weight of u-v plus distance value of u, then 
       update the distance value of v.
```

I was thinking of implementing this pseudocode in C++ for Dijkstra . This is for the fast implementation . I have some confusion here ie , we are using a heap to keep a track of the Dijkstra score of adjacent vertices of the unexplored region . In 3b we need to check for every adjacent vertex v of u , check if v is minHeap , does minHeap support such a operation in constant time , heaps are the worst data structures for searching , it should take linear time for searching whether it is there in min heap or not , moreover we have to update the adjacent vertices so not only we should know whether it is in minHeap or not but even it's location so that we can update it , we want all this to happen in logv time otherwise there is no point of fast implementation . 
What data structure should be used in place of Heap ?

PS : I am talking about an implementation where the graph is implemented as a adjacency list .

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: How to get elogv with heaps ?

Comment: So this is not your question ? `What data structure should be used in place of Heap ? `

Comment: i mean , should we use something other that heap or modify the heap implementation somehow so that it can support the search operation in constant time ?

Comment: isn't my question clear ?

Comment: You can use Brodal's and Okasaki's Priority Queue or Fibonacci's heap, which decrease asymptotic to O(vlogv + e)

Answer (score 2):

In worst case scenario Dijkstra's algorithm has to perform `|E|` DecreaseKey operations and `|V|` ExtractMin operations.

1. In binary heap data structure cost of both DecreaseKey and ExtractMin operations are O(log(n)). So the total cost of algorithm is `O(|E|log(|V|) + |V|log(|V|))`
2. If we use fibonacci heap instead of simple binary heap we can reduce the total cost to `O(|E| + |V|log(|V|))` because now amortized cost of DecreaseKey operation is `O(1)`

In addition for every vertex from your graph you have to maintain an array of pointers to corresponding elements of the heap. So that you can identify vertex in the heap in `O(1)`